# iPad stuck on Guided Access with broken home button

Tags: ipad

My iPad is stuck on Guided Access. I do remember the passcode but my home button is broken. I've been using the on-screen home button but that too is disabled. Will draining the battery out fix my problem or is there another way?

Answer (score -2):

After a quick google search, I found [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QXX2afoAinI) video that may help you, depending on what version of iOS you have. There are many other tutorials on youtube that you should check out as well.

Good Luck!